# Correct term for initially neutral mutations that subsequently cannot be reversed

Tags: genetics, evolution, proteins, terminology, mutations

Can anyone tell me what the correct name is for a neutral mutation to a protein that occurs when that mutation becomes "locked in" due to a subsequent mutation?

For example: mutation A is neutral initially and can be reversed with no deleterious effects, but after mutation B, the reversal of mutation A would now become deleterious. What is the correct terminology for a mutation of A's type?

Comment: silent mutation?

Comment: Silent mutations are mutations in DNA that do not significantly alter the phenotype of the organism in which they occur. Silent mutations can occur in non-coding regions (outside of genes or within introns), or they may occur within exons.

Comment: Well, what will happen is proceeding to [fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(population_genetics)) if A does, but I don't think that really answers your question. The answer could be [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_mutation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutation A is a *suppressor* of Mutation B. The Wikipedia article on the topic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppressor_mutation) mostly describes situations where Mutation A occurs after B and reverses B's deleterious effects, but the principle is the same.